# VB Script - Unsure how to code for 81 possible results

Tags: vbscript, word-2003

Firstly thanks for looking at the question and any help is much appreciated.

My Problem: I have 9 String variables and want these to show in a 'roundup' String to display content if a value exists for it. So I'm expecting I need multiple If statements to cover all the possible outcomes.

Example if variable a= "12/11/11" and b ="" c="21/12/12 d= "12/03/11" e ="" and f="11/12/13

I have a roundUp String variable that displays these values but only if they have content. So I need to cator for all combinations. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to describe the underlying logic/input & desired result more clearly I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check the status of 9 variables and then "rollup" all of them into one string variable to output, in which case you want to concatenate your output variable.  Something like below should work (and there might be a more elegant solution)

Dim Roundup

Roundup = ""

If a="12/11/11" Then 
Roundup = Roundup + " A value trapped"
End if

If b="" Then 
Roundup = Roundup + " B value trapped" 
End If

.. and so on...

Comment: thankyou for the response even if I was a little late :)